# Page object Model discussion

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, page-objects

I am building a test framework for my Website using Selenium, I actually want your ideas of good practices when using Page Object Model: let us say that I have a Welcome page that contains a header where logout button exists, and this header can be seen in most of my pages I am thinking that it is better to write a separate class for the header something like this:

```
public class Header
    {
    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "user_profile")]
    public IWebElement BtnUserProfile{ get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "logout_button")]
    public IWebElement BtnLogout { get; set; }

    public void Logout()
     {
        BtnLogout.Click();
     }
}

public class LoginPage
    {
    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "username")]
    public IWebElement TxtbxUserName { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "password")]
    public IWebElement TxtbxPassword { get; set; }

    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "button")]
    public IWebElement BtnSignIn { get; set; }


    public string GoTO()
   {
       Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(LoginURL);
   }
    public void Login(string username, string password)
     {
        TxtbxUserName.SendKeys(username);
        TxtbxPassword.SendKeys(password);
        BtnSignIn.Click();
     }
    public bool IsAt()
     {
         return Driver.Url == LoginURL;
     }
}

public class WelcomePage
   {
    [FindsBy(How = How.Name, Using = "welcome-message")]
    public IWebElement LblWelcomeMessage { get; set; }
}
```

My question is do you think it is better to include the Header as a property in the Welcome Page or should they be separated?

Let us take the code for Logout test method, for example.

**Case 1:**

```
public void LogoutTest()
{
    LoginPage loginpage= new LoginPage();
    loginpage.GoTo();
    loginpage.login("user","pass");
    Header header= new Header();
    header.Logout();
    Assert.IsTrue(loginpage.IsAt());
}
```

**Case 2:**

```
public void LogoutTest()
{
    LoginPage loginpage= new LoginPage();
    loginpage.GoTo();
    loginpage.login("user","pass");
    WelcomePage wlcmPage= new WelcomePage();
    WelcomePage.Logout();
    Assert.IsTrue(loginpage.IsAt());
}
```

The second question will be, how do you think about writing a static class for the Driver instead of a separate Driver for every page.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. > My question is do you think it is better to include the Header as a property in the Welcome Page or should they be separated?

   Yes, logically, a header is a property of the welcome page. You can implement a header as a property of a generic page, then inherit from this generic page.
2. > The second question will be, how do you think about writing a static class for the Driver instead of a separate Driver for every page.

   This is a good idea, logically, there is only one driver instance, all we are doing is to pass it different parameters.